# SQL COUNT(*) Confusion

Tags: sql

This is from a book Murachs SQL Server for Developers:

I have this summary query that calculates the number of invoices and the average invoice amount for the vendors in each state and city group. I understand the majority of the code but one part that confuses me is the `COUNT(*)` aggregate. According to the book, this aggregate will get the number of invoices a State, City Group has.

I cannot seem to follow the logic to me it looks like the `COUNT(*)` in the `SELECT` statement will give a total of how many times a vendor state/city group will appear in the vendor's table not in the invoices table.

```
SELECT   VendorState, VendorCity, COUNT(*) AS 'Invoice QTY',
         AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS 'InvoiceAvg'
FROM     Invoices JOIN Vendors
ON       Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
GROUP BY VendorState, VendorCity
HAVING   COUNT(*) >= 2
ORDER BY VendorState, VendorCity;`
```

Comment: The best way to understand would be to remove the `count(*)/avg()` and `group by` from the query and examine the returned rows using `select *`. You'd see a row per invoice and each matching vendor. The aggregation works on this initial set of rows. After grouping by the state & city, the aggregate counts the number of rows in each of these unique groups - filtering out any group less than 2 rows.

Comment: Ah, I see it now thank you a lot been trying to hammer it out for hours now lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would parse your query:

```
SELECT   VendorState, VendorCity, COUNT(*) AS 'Invoice QTY',
         AVG(InvoiceTotal) AS 'InvoiceAvg'
```

Okay, you select some blah blah. I'd come back here after parsing to see whether the chosen columns are really available, but here you have no errors so I'll assume the columns are good.

```
FROM     Invoices
```

You start with *all the invoices* (perhaps this is the point that confuses you).

```
JOIN Vendors
ON       Invoices.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
```

Each Invoice is joined to a single Vendor (VendorID is a primary key), so **the cardinality does not change** (assuming all vendors are still in place of course; an invoice with no matching VendorId will "disappear". Usually this is not the case when invoices and vendors are involved; you might have a flag to exclude "terminated" vendors, but you wouldn't remove invoices from the database). The important thing is, if you had 1,000 invoices, you now have 1,000 rows after the JOIN, not 2,000 or any other number. So, you're still working with invoices.

```
GROUP BY VendorState, VendorCity
```

Okay, so the COUNT(*) refers to the *invoices* of each single city in each single state. The HAVING clause restricts the results to those cities where at least two invoices are present.

Comment: Yea the point that was confusing me was that I was not visualizing properly the JOIN still having a 1:1 cardinality. Following the order of operations of the different clauses helps too. Thanks, m8!

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, the `HAVING` clause is evaluated after the `JOIN` is performed. So the number of rows counted will be the number of invoices (less any invoices that are missing a valid vendorID, and thus fail to Join)

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest writing the query as:

```
SELECT v.VendorState, v.VendorCity,
       COUNT(*) AS InvoiceQTY, AVG(i.InvoiceTotal) AS InvoiceAvg
FROM Invoices i JOIN
     Vendors v 
     ON i.VendorID = v.VendorID
GROUP BY v.VendorState, v.VendorCity
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
ORDER BY v.VendorState, v.VendorCity;
```

The changes are:

- Use table aliases to make the query easier to write and read.
- Qualify all column references.
- Only use single quotes for strings, not column names.
- Avoid column names that need to be escaped.

The `COUNT(*)` is counting neither the number of "vendors" nor "invoices" -- well, not directly.  It is counting the number of rows that match after the `JOIN` takes place.

Based on your naming convention, each invoice matches exactly one vendor.  So, when you use `COUNT(*)` you are counting *invoices*, not vendors.